Question about the toroidal magnetic field in quasars and the role of an ergosphere
1) Introduction
Most of astrophysical bodies (in this context: formed stars, young stellar objects and black holes) produce or are immersed in a non-zero magnetic field $\vec{B}$. It is common, since we are talking about a spheric or axisymmetric system $(t,r,\theta, \phi)$, that the (spatial) magnetic field have a poloidal $\vec{B}_{P}$ component and a toroidal component $\vec{B}_{T}$ $[1]$:
$$\vec{B} = [\vec{B}_{P}] + \vec{B}_{T} = [\vec{B}_{r}+\vec{B}_{\theta}] + \vec{B}_{\phi}.\tag{1}$$
Now, a magnetohydrodynamical effect that is common in astrophysical bodies is called "differential rotation" $[1]$. The differential rotation then "drags" the magnetic field lines, like in the Figure 14.13 $[1]$, and then produces a pure toroidal magnetic field:

2) My question
We can see in this image $[2]$ a jet reaching out regions quite far from the galactic centre, and the  two most accepted mechanisms on how these structures are formed, are the famous Blandford-Znajek (BZ) $[3]$ and Blandford-Payne (BP) $[4]$ processes.
In Blandford-Znajek process, it is said that the (pure poloidal) magnetic field lines anchored $[*],[5]$ in the astrophysical plasma, are dragged close to the black hole. Then, due to the physical properties of the ergosphere (the field lines cannot counter-rotate the hole) and the enormous frame-dragging effect, these lines are twisted, forming a pure toroidal magnetic field, which collimate the particles into a jet structure $[**]$.
My question is:

It seems, therefore, in stars the toroidal field lines are generated by differential rotation; in black holes, due to the frame-dragging. So, in a astrophysical black hole system, the role of an ergosphere is just to ignite the electromagnetic Penrose process (a.k.a the Blandford-Znajek process) or the ergosphere is essential for a pure toroidal magnetic field  to be formed $[***]$?


$[1]$ Arnab Rai Chaudhuri - The Physics of Fluids and Plasmas, Cambridge University Press (1998). PAGE: 348
$[2]$ https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:M87_jet.jpg
$[3]$ Blandford, R. D.; Znajek, R. L. (1977-07-01). "Electromagnetic extraction of energy from Kerr black holes". Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society. 179 (3): 433–456. doi:10.1093/mnras/179.3.433. ISSN 0035-8711.
$[4]$ Blandford, R. D., & Payne, D. G. 1982, MNRAS, 199, 883
$[5]$ Thorne, K. S., Price, R. H., and Macdonald, D. A. (1986). Black Hole: The Membrane Paradigm (New Heaven: Yale University Press)
$[*]$ They are anchored because since a plasma have a high conductivity $\sigma$, the magnetic viscosity $D_{B} \approx 0$ is close to zero. Then, the temporal and spatial variations of the magnetic field are very small: $\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t} = D_{B}\nabla ^{2}\vec{B} = 0$. (Alexander Fridman, Lawrence A. Kennedy. Plasma Physics and Engineering, 2023, [PAGE 274].)
$[**]$ The BZ process is a kind of Penrose process, but is not clear for me yet, how the particles are accelerated.
$[***]$ Note that the frame-dragging effect do not require a ergosphere, e.g. in the weak field metric near planets.
